# Can't find module in AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have 2 nearly similar code in my AWS lambda :

This one is working :

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    console.log("works fine");
};
```

Otherwise, this one doesn't work :

```
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
};
```

It is causing this error :

```
Unable to import module 'index': Error
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
```

My file is at the root and is called index.js
My manager is set to index.handler

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Are you deploying the Alexa SDK with your Lambda function? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

Answer (score 1):

Only the aws-sdk package is preinstalled with Nodejs For AWS Lambda .

You should also put your node_modules folder in the package you upload to
AWS Lambda .

In the comments some one have you the right link: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html)

So you create a folder , put your index.js inside it,
init an npm package (with: npm init) and then install the alexa package.

```
npm -i alexa-sdk
```

Put both index.js and node_modules in the zip file,
then re-upload .

it should work for you now .